# Не получается написать unit тест для метода register класса ErrorHandler

Tags: php, ооп

Пытаюсь написать проверку метода register в для класса ErrorHandler

Тест выглядит так:

```
<?php
/**
 * phpunit vendor/meow/core/tests/ErrorHandlerTest
 */
namespace tests\meow\core;

use meow\core\ErrorHandler;

class ErrorHandlerTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    protected $handler;

    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->handler = new ErrorHandler();
    }

    protected function turnDown()
    {
        $this->handler = null;
    }

    public function testRegister()
    {
        $this->handler->register();
        $this->assertEquals(E_ALL, error_reporting());
    }
}
```

сам метод выглядит так:

```
public static function register()
{
    ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    set_error_handler(get_class() . "::showError");
    register_shutdown_function(get_class() . "::catch_fatal_error");
    ob_start();
}
```

Ошибку выдает следующую:

> Fatal error: Uncaught ob_end_flush(): failed to delete and flush buffer. No buffer to delete or flush

Пробовал различные манипуляции с буфером (удалить, вывести, очистить) но ничего не помогает избавиться от ошибки и пройти успешно тест.

Скорее всего я неправильно что-то использую, но что?
Как правильнее организовать тест для такого метода?

Сильно не плюйтесь, учу php дома сам, поэтому некоторые вещи, возможно простые, не могу догнать быстро. Мануалы читаю регулярно, но понимаю их с большим трудом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первое: вы не можете так протестировать обработчик ошибок. Устанавливая обработчик ошибок, вы вторгаетесь в глобальную область, а модульные тесты должны быть изолированными, чтобы не влиять на другие тесты - его можно только запустить в отдельном процессе. По факту, любой обработчик состоит из двух компонент - функционала обработки ошибок и непосредственно регистрации этого функционала. За регистрацию отвечает сам PHP, поэтому тестировать его бестолку, поэтому собственно такой тест и не нужен.

Второе: вам не нужно вообще работать с буфером. Ошибка, скорее всего, вызвана тем, что буфер открывается и не закрывается (хотя ее текст и говорит немного об ином), но в обработке ошибок он никак вам не поможет. Сам код, тем не менее, напрямую ошибок не содержит, а ошибку вызывает какой-то сторонний функционал.

Comment: Т.е. вы хотите сказать, что такой тест в принципе не нужен?

Я работаю с буфером, чтоб предотвратить отправку данных о фатальной ошибке пользователю, и отослать свои данные. Так делать нельзя? Или просто конкретно в этих методах так делать не нужно?

Comment: @Razzwan Так вообще делать не нужно. Скрытие отображения ошибок для пользователя делается через display_errors, фатальную ошибку еще надо суметь вызвать (обычно это говорит о том, что код не работает в принципе). Тест действительно не нужен, потому что сейчас он просто проверяет вызовы функций PHP, и их тестировать должны совсем не вы.